# Android dx generates bad checksum dex files

Tags: android

I'm working on a project which generates Java code on-the-fly, and compiles it for Android. Funny thing is that sometimes **dx.bat** generates a broken DEX file while finishing successfully.

When I try to dexdump the DEX, I get: **ERROR: bad checksum (deadbeef vs deadc0de)**

Manually playing around with *--no-optimize* or *--no-locals* will solve the issue for this specific compilation. But you can never know what will happen with the next one and this is a process that should be reliable.

BTW, manually fixing the checksum doesn't fix the problem (dexdump will crash after dumping some data) so I figure it isn't a dx checksum calculation bug.

Is there a known issue? How can I further debug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bug in `Windows' version of DexDump` (and some other tools).

Will be fixed in r11.

See full bug report at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14746